# Considering Google Compute Engine to supplement our AWS stack, some comparison questions

Tags: ruby, google-compute-engine

We're exploring using GCE alongside out AWS deployment and I've a few questions coming from AWS.

1. It doesn't seem like the GCE Load Balancers support SSL (as in encrypting http traffic into https via the load balancer). I saw in the docs that its something that's coming .. does anyone know any good workarounds and possibly the timelines for actual support of this?
2. We use SQS on AWS a fair bit, and would like to use something simillar on GCE. There looks like there is Task Queues, but we've had a lot of trouble making them work in Ruby, for various issues, the docs seem somewhat lacking even trying to test them out in the builtin "try it out" tool. Does anyone have experience with having them work that could point us to a) a working ruby client library for it b) perhaps more complete docs (we have not even been able to issue a single authenticated request to them)
3. PubSub, we use SNS on AWS, and would like something simillar on GCE. Is PubSub the answer? It seems like its in invitation only beta right now? Any idea how we can get in and play with it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, because you're asking three different questions. Keeping answers organized will be really difficult, and will result in a poor result when people search and find this. Please consider rewriting it to cover one each, and show what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: To answer your first question, the workaround for it is by using a reverse proxy. I will search about the other two questions and will get back to you once I have enough information.